# ¿Cómo hacer una tabla pivote en PosgreSQL?

Tags: sql, postgresql

Tengo los siguientes datos:

```
predio_id     tipo_animal_id    cantidad
Predio 2           2               1
Predio 2           3               3
Predio 2           4               1
Predio 2           6               5
Predio 2           7               5
Predio 3           2               1
Predio 3           4               1
Predio 4           6               1
Predio 4           7               1
```

Necesito agrupar los predios y que los tipos de animales queden como columnas.
Este debiera ser el resultado:

```
   predio_id cantidad_tipo_2 cantidad_tipo_3 cantidad_tipo_4 cantidad_tipo_6 cantidad_tipo_7 
   Predio 2         1              3                1             5                 5
   Predio 3         1              0                1             0                 0
   Predio 4         0              0                0             1                 1
```

Tabla predio

```
id     nombre
```

Tabla ganado_predio

```
id     ganado_fk   predio_fk
```

Tabla ganado

```
id      ganado_predio_fk   tipo_animal_fk
```

Tabla tipo_animal

```
id     nombre
```

Comment: Bienvenido a [Stack Overflow en Español](http://es.stackoverflow.com/tour). Para futuras preguntas que tengas, 
te recomiendo leer esta guía acerca de cómo preguntar, para así obtener reputación y añadir valor a nuestro sitio. Volviendo a tu pregunta, ¿cuáles son las tablas involucradas en la consulta? por favor actualiza tu pregunta.

Comment: Que motor de Bd Utilizas? Sql Server, Oracle, MySql,Postgres,etc..

Comment: Utilizo PostgreSQL

Comment: Una especie de pivot table?

Answer (score 2):

danielctf, este es el código para que te muestre el resultado, siendo tu tabla con nombre (predio)

```
select 
    predio_id,
    [2] AS 'cantidad_tipo_2',
    [3] AS 'cantidad_tipo_3',
    [4] AS 'cantidad_tipo_4',
    [5] AS 'cantidad_tipo_5',
    [6] AS 'cantidad_tipo_6',
    [7] AS 'cantidad_tipo_7'
from(
    select predio_id,tipo_animal_id,cantidad
    from predio
) as source
pivot
(
    sum(cantidad)
    for tipo_animal_id in ( 
                        [2],
                        [3],
                        [4],
                        [5],
                        [6],
                        [7]
                    )
) as pvt
```